# There's a folder called "C:" in my wordpress root that cannot be deleted over SSH

Tags: ssh, directory, delete

I migrated my wordpress install from a Windows machine to an Ubuntu machine and I had the script `WPBackup` installed. The path for the backup was `C:/webserver/site/wp-content/backup/` for the old install, I forgot to purge these settings before the move and when I moved it to the Ubuntu server and the scheduled database backup job ran, it created a really strange folder that I cannot seem to get rid of.

The folder is called `C:` when connecting via `ssh`, and is located in the website's root folder:

```
6422653 drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data   4096 okt  6 03:24 C:
```

The folder in samba is called `CQFO6Q~M`

I cannot go to the folder through `ssh`, it tells me:

```
-bash: cd: /var/www/site/c: No such file or directory
```

same for `CQFO6Q~M`

```
-bash: cd: /var/www/site/CQFO6Q~M No such file or directory
```

I can browse the folder over samba but I cannot delete it as it's owned by `www-data` but I cannot `chmod` the folder as it doesn't exist.

How can I find the "real name" of this folder and delete it over ssh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux filesystems are case-sensitive. There is no `c:` directory, only a `C:` one. So, try removing it using the right name:

```
rm -rf C:
```